# Set a single AnimatedVisibility to true in a LazyColumn

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn

I have a Composable function for operating system infos which expands it details upon click and reverts when clicked again.

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun OSCard(os: OS) {
    var expanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .clickable { expanded = !expanded }
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(20.dp),
            text = os.name,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
        )
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = expanded) {
            Text(text = os.description, modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
        }
        Divider(Modifier.height(2.dp))
    }
}
```

I created a list of it and passed it through a `LazyColumn`

```
var OSs = listOf<OS>(
    OS(
        "Android",
        "Android is a mobile/desktop operating system..."
      ),
    OS(
        "Microsoft Windows",
        "Microsoft Windows, commonly referred to as Windows..."
      ),
    OS(
        "Linux",
        "Linux is a family of open-source Unix-like operating systems..."
      )
)

Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(items =  OSs){
            os -> OSCard(os)
        }
    }
}
```

While it works as expected, I want to make it such that if a card is opened and another card is selected, the previously opened card will be closed.

This is what I am trying to avoid, can someone give me a tip on how to?

[image: What I am trying to avoid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. Add a parameter to your OS object called `isExpanded`. It only gets set to true when you click on a card. The click handler will clear the flag in all the other cards.

I also added an `id` parameter which makes it easier to find the item being clicked. The `name` parameter could have been used.

The state variable `expandCard` needs to read for it to trigger a recompose, so `var e = expandCard` is used to read the value.  Also note that the creation of your list MUST be outside of the composable, otherwise it would just end up getting re-created and the isExpanded field would be set to false on all items.

And lastly, I'm not sure why you're using a LazyColumn for this. LazyColumn is really meant for large datasets and primarily for paging. You could just use a normal Column with vertical scrolling if you have a reasonable number of items.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @ExperimentalAnimationApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var OSs = listOf(
            OS(
                id = "android",
                name = "Android",
                description =  "Android is a mobile/desktop operating system..."
            ),
            OS(
                id = "mswindows",
                name = "Microsoft Windows",
                description = "Microsoft Windows, commonly referred to as Windows..."
            ),
            OS(
                id = "linux",
                name ="Linux",
                description = "Linux is a family of open-source Unix-like operating systems..."
            )
        )

        setContent {

            var expandCard by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            var e = expandCard

            Surface() {
                LazyColumn(  modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    itemsIndexed(
                        items = OSs,
                        key = { index, os ->
                            os.name
                        }
                    ) { index, os ->
                        OSCard(os) {osClicked ->
                            val isExpanded = osClicked.isExpanded
                            OSs.forEach { it.isExpanded = false }
                            OSs.first { it.id == osClicked.id }.isExpanded = isExpanded
                            expandCard = !expandCard
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun OSCard(
    os: OS,
    onClick: (os: OS) -> Unit
) {

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
            os.isExpanded = !os.isExpanded
            onClick(os)
        }
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(20.dp),
            text = os.name,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
        )

        AnimatedVisibility(visible = os.isExpanded) {
            Text(text = os.description, modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
        }
        Divider(Modifier.height(2.dp))
    }
}

class OS(var id: String, var name: String, var description: String, var isExpanded: Boolean= false)
```

Comment: I am so glad for the answer as well as the explanations of what to do and what not.

I appreciate the knowledge shared. Thank you.